# module import in windows

Tags: python

I am new to windows and I am working on setting up code and modules with visual studio.

I have the following folder structure for my code:

```
myModule
  __init__.py
  mymodule.py
myScript
  myscript.py
```

In myscript.py I have the following command:

```
from myModule import *
```

In visual studio this command works, but when I run the script command line I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named myModule
```

Is there a quick trick in windows to do the job w/o having to install myModule as a package?

Any of the usual tricks that work in linux don't seem to work in windows.  I.e.,

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'myModule'))
```

or,

```
import ..myModule
```

Comment: @RobertB you mean you use sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), r"..", 'myModule')).. I tried but it doesn't work for me, maybe i have something else messed up

Comment: Wouldn't `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')` be enough. Then `import myModule` should find it.

Comment: @RobertB you are the master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path should have entries that point to the module. Your path entry is pointing inside the module.

What you had:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), r"..", 'myModule')
```

Instead, you want to point to the directory containing myModule, which would be:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), r"..")
```